Before 2013, did multiples inputs necessarily belong to a single user?
I am all new to bitcoin and would like to make some studies for a datascience project.
I'm focussing on the visualization of some chains of transactions where I could visualize users by some color scheme or pictogram.
I gather that in 2013 the so-called mixers started to occur which allowed different users to feature as different inputs of a transaction.
My question is : can I assume that before 2013 in any transaction the different inputs all belonged to a single user?
If not was it the case in 2010 or in 2009?

Not categorically, no. I think it has pretty much always possible to apply signatures one-by-one, but it has become a lot less arduous over time to create multi-sender transactions. However, I would surmise that even today you would be right almost always to assume that all inputs are controlled by a single entity, especially if you special case obvious coinjoin transactions.

Ha great, thank you!

Is there a claim for the earliest multi-sender transaction? Maybe Satoshi and Hal tested it?

Interesting question! I don’t know of one from the top of my head, but that would make a great follow up question. Could you start a topic for that?

Thanks, I have done so at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/124461/what-is-the-earliest-multi-sender-transaction
