What is the earliest multi-sender transaction?
Is there a claim for the earliest multi-sender transaction?
Maybe Satoshi and Hal tested it?

I think amaclin's answer illustrates that we can't easily distinguish between multi-sender transactions and single-sender multi-input transactions with certainty. It might have been better to ask about what murch called "obvious coinjoin transactions" in murch's answer to your earlier question on this theme.

Obviously my question requires some extra knowledge on top of transaction data, which is usually not available, but for very early transaction I expect some comments on forums to provide the extra data.

The earliest transaction with more than one input
https://mempool.space/tx/a3b0e9e7cddbbe78270fa4182a7675ff00b92872d8df7d14265a2b1e379a9d33
The earliest transaction with more than one output ( Satoshi -> Hal )
https://mempool.space/tx/f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16

Thank you. The first one is presumably all Satoshi though, not multi-sender, given the block numbers of the 50 coins from coinbase that led to the 1, the 10 and the 50 (Hal started mining at block 78) and there is the Patoshi pattern to allow guessing Satoshi's blocks.
